# Python: How to get multiple variables from a URL in Flask?

Tags: python, url, get, request, flask

I'm trying to get multiple arguments from a url in Flask. After reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15182724/1650012) I thought I could do it like this:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/getQ/', methods=['GET'])
def getQ(request):
    print request.args.get('a')
    print request.args.get('b')
    return "lalala"
```

But when I visit `/api/v1/getQ/a=1&b=2`, I get a `TypeError: getQ() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`. I tried other urls, like `/api/v1/getQ/?a=1&b=2` and `/api/v1/getQ?a=1&b=2`, but to no avail.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Your function getQ(request) is expecting an argument (request here). That's the problem, your function should not take any argument.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You misread the error message; the exception is about how `getQ` is called with *python* arguments, not how many URL parameters you added to invoke the view.

Flask views don't take `request` as a function argument, but use it as a global context instead. Remove `request` from the function signature:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/api/v1/getQ/', methods=['GET'])
def getQ():
    print request.args.get('a')
    print request.args.get('b')
    return "lalala"
```

Your syntax to access URL parameters is otherwise perfectly correct. Note that `methods=['GET']` is the default for routes, you can leave that off.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this to get multiple arguments from a url in Flask:

--- **curl request**---

```
curl -i "localhost:5000/api/foo/?a=hello&b=world"
```

--- **flask server**---

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/foo/', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    bar = request.args.to_dict()
    print bar
    return 'success', 200

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---**print bar**---

```
{'a': u'hello', 'b': u'world'}
```

P.S. Don't omit double quotation("  ") with curl option, or it not work in Linux cuz "&"

similar question [Multiple parameters in in Flask approute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182696/multiple-parameters-in-in-flask-approute/38987737#38987737)

Comment: The "" with curl for multiple query strings solved the problem that I was beating my head against.  TYSM!