# Two arguments in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to call some functions and return the results in the browser but I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I have this code following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182696/multiple-parameters-in-in-flask-approute) answer

```
from flask import  Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def message():
  return "Message from python function named 'message' "

@app.route("/user/<username>")
def user(username):
  return "Username is %s " % username

@app.route("/userpass/<username>/<password>")
def userpass(username, password):
  return "User is %s and password %s " % username % password
```

and I am calling the first one just by using

> http://127.0.0.1:5000

the second one using

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/test

and the last one by using

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/userpass/test/123

and I get the error 500. What's the problem with the last call?

Comment: Using password for url parameter, wow! I think you are on a wrong path.

Comment: @vishes_shell haha, it's just for test reasons!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your return statement in the failing route should look like this:

`return "User is %s and password %s " % (username, password)`

Comment: Is there a way to overcome the "self" parameter error with flask? I am getting a missing argument error while calling the function because of the self parameter I have to use which flask takes it as an extra argument

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2**

The accepted answer works. However, %-formatting method is old and is [not best practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#rationale).

The [best practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#specification) is to use the [`format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), like so:

```
return "User is {} and password {}".format(username, password)
```

---

**Python 3.6+**

[f-Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) is [the way to go](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

```
return f"User is {username} and password {password}"
```