# Flask only accept single json variable and crashed when setting two variables

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, internal-server-error

I am building a web crawler app on Google App Engine. I want to use a post method to pass the variable to Flask. Then, the received variable became the input of my web crawler app. However, Flask only accept single variable from post. If I add another variable in the funciton， Flask would crash.

I have limited knowledge in Flask and Google app engine. I struggled with the problem for several days and your help will be highly appreciated.

**Failed function**

```
#server-side function that does not work,with 2 variable passed
@app.route('/bac',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bac():
    request_json = request.get_json()
    filename = request_json["filename"]
    url = request_json["url"]
    #baseconnect.Baseconnect(url=url,filename=filename).run()
    return filename,url

#The function to post on client side

import requests
req = requests.Session()
data = req.post('https://project.appspot.com/bac',json={"filename":"yuan","url":"https:...f5"})
print(data.text)

#output:
 Internal server eror 500
```

**Succeeded function**

```
#server-side function that works,with 1 variable passed
@app.route('/bac',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bac():
    request_json = request.get_json()
    filename = request_json["filename"]
    #url = request_json["url"]
    #baseconnect.Baseconnect(url=url,filename=filename).run()
    return filename

#The function to post on client side

import requests
req = requests.Session()
data = req.post('https://project.appspot.com/bac',json={"filename":"yuan"})
print(data.text)
#output:
 yuan
```

Flask seems only accept single variable. What is the problem....

Comment: Is `filename` actually defined?

Comment: yes, when the crawling task finished, the output will use the filename.

Comment: That's weird. As far as I know, `request.args.get` only gets the query string in URL, which is not specified here.

Comment: Can you try to print `filename` inside the route after `request.args.get()`?

Comment: And also, route url should start with a '/'. Change `route` to `'/route'`.

Comment: Hello, Wang, I was testing the function in the previous hour and correct several error that you pointed out. Thank you very much!
Now, I realized that the problem is that Flask could only accept single variable. If i set two variable then it will response internal server error 500. It is quite weried.

Comment: [this link might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182696/multiple-parameters-in-in-flask-approute)

Comment: @RNHTTR  I want to say THANK YOU~~. That is the problem. I did not know flask had the difference with a normal Python function. You helped me a lot~

Comment: np :) @GMarsh did all the hard work in his response to the question i linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have here is that Flask only returns `Response` object, and Flask will consider `return filename, url` a shortcut of `return Response, status or header`.

In this case, `url` becomes the http status code or header, which is obviously not right.

You need `flask.jsonify()` to return the proper format of so called 'multiple variables'.

Something like this: (only the important part)

```py
# In server-side code
from flask import jsonify
@app.route('/bac',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bac():
    request_json = request.get_json()
    filename = request_json["filename"]
    url = request_json["url"]
    # Do your logic here
    return jsonify({ filename_returned: filename, url_returned: url })


# client-side
import requests
req = requests.Session()
json_data = req.post('https://project.appspot.com/bac',json={"filename":"yuan", "url": "http:xxxxxxx"})
real_data = json.loads(json_data)
# real_data should be the result you want
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind instruction. It did help me solve the problem. I am so happy that I could run my app properly!