# Pass 2 parameters in url for app.route (python with flask )

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Try to pass two parameters but seems like I'm missing something with syntax here , can someone help me on this?

```
@app.route('/BotMetrics/<int:fromdate>/<int:todate>')
def user(fromdate, todate):
     print("connecting")
     con = Get_hdb()
     cursor1 = con.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
     cursor1.execute("select * from order_details where date between '%s' and '%s'",(fromdate,todate,))
     row = cursor1.fetchall()
     resp = jsonify(row)
     resp.status_code = 200
     return resp
```

Trying to access URL , here I want to pass two parameters FromDate and ToDate in URL ,

http://127.0.0.1:5000/BotMetrics/?FromDate?Todate

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369873/4985099

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple parameters in Flask approute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182696/multiple-parameters-in-flask-approute)

Answer (score 1):

Updated the code to below and it worked

```
@app.route('/BotMetrics/<fromdate>/<todate>')
def user(fromdate=None, todate=None):
     print("connecting")
     con = Get_hdb()
     cursor1 = con.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
     cursor1.execute("select * from order_details where date between %s and %s",(fromdate,todate,))
     row = cursor1.fetchall()
     resp = jsonify(row)
     resp.status_code = 200
     return resp
```

URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/BotMetrics/2021-02-01/2021-02-27
```